# Selecting different tables in nHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, sql, nhibernate

I need to execute a query that will return N tables. in my program, i have the following tables (some of them):

TABLES:

1. HM_RECEIVE;
2. HM_SEND;
3. SM_RECEIVE;
4. SM_SEND;
5. P_SLAB;
6. P_SLAB_PDO;
7. ...

Entities:

1. HMreceive;
2. HMsend;
3. SMreceive;
4. SMsend;
5. PSlab;
6. PSlabPDO;
7. ...

I have two questions, and this would be nicer if i could accomplish it using only one criteria:

1. How do I select all tables? In first moment I believe there's no need to match IDs, but if changes anything I really would like to know;
2. Is there a way to select only HM and SM tables, ignoring all others?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

How I do something like: select * from HMReceive, SMReceive, HMSend, SMSend?

Comment: I cannot see how the example SQL query, `select * from HMRecieve, SMReceive, ....`, could be useful.  Do you really want to cross join all of your tables together?  This would be very bad for performance - lots and lots of duplicated data would have to be fetched from the database.  It would be better to issue separate queries for each table.

Comment: If there's another way to get all those 4 tables ( as easiest as possible ) without criteria for every table, then joining all in one LINQ, i really like to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables have similar layout, you could use inheritance.

Define the classes similar to:

```
public class HMReceive : BaseClass


public class HMSend : BaseClass


public class SMReceive : BaseClass


public class SMSend : BaseClass
```

and you can use HQL to

```
select * from BaseClass
```

or use criteria to query against BaseClass.  The result will be an IList but each entity returned will consist of the actual type HMReceive, HMSend, SMReceive, or SMSend.

Comment: Thanks. I've develop another way but it's very similar to this one. I've created another entity with only the columns i'll gonna use. But i'm using HQL with .CreateSQLQuery() so... thanks for the tip.

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. There are two possibilities here:
If BaseClass is also mapped, then indeed the select will handle all the related tables in one go.
If BaseClass is not mapped, then NHibernate will generate one SELECT for each mapped subclass of BaseClass.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure about your requirement, but using NHibernate, there are several ways to fetch multiple tables in a single query:

Using eager fetching if your tables connect with each other. Following query will fetch child records along with their Parent:

```
session.QueryOver<Child>().Fetch(child => child.Parent).Eager.List();
```

If the tables are not connect with each other, and your database is Oracle, then you are out of luck. But with MS SQL Server, you can use Future() to make multiple queries to go to database at once:

```
// Future() returns a lazy enumerable, not actually queries the database.
var childs = session.QueryOver<Child>().Future(); 
// NHibernate will populate the lazy enumerable once it being enumerated, 
// or when it has to hit the database anyway, like when a call to List() happen:
var parents =session.QueryOver<Parent>().List();
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately we're using Oracle. 
Another question (and this will be added on my first post), with nHibernate can I make a custom query with SQL?
I could do something like:
    select * from HMReceive, SMReceive, HMSend, SMSend;
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking for a way to fetch pretty much all of the data in the database.  You really should just fetch only the data that you need.  That said, sometimes it is useful to be able to fetch data from tables without having to explicitly name the tables that you want to fetch from.  For example, you may want to write a unit test that simply verifies that the NHibernate mappings correctly match your database schema.  Ayende has a [blog post illustrating how to write such a test](http://ayende.com/blog/1595/nhibernate-mapping-creating-sanity-checks).  This is a slightly modified version of that test:

```
[Test]
public void SchemaShouldMatchMappings()
{
    // `GetAllClassMetadata` returns a collection of all of the mapped entities.
    foreach (var entry in _sessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata())
    {
        // Build a query that fetches this entity...
        _session.CreateCriteria(entry.Value.EntityName)
            // ... but tell it to just check the schema and not actually bring any back.
            .SetMaxResults(0)
            // Execute the query.
            .List();
    }
}
```

I think you can use a loop similar to the above as a starting point for what you are trying to accomplish.  I'm not going to actually post a code example that fetches all of the data in the database because I don't want to encourage people to do bad things - but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Daniel Schilling, but i've found another way to make it work. But I liked your implementation, once i finish this I think I'll try it.